# Seaborn: how to set bar borders' line width or color?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to draw a barplot with bars with no borders. By default bars has thin black borders. In the devlopment version (0.6) of Seaborn, I could pass kwargs (`linewidth`, `edgecolor`) to `pyplot.bar()` via `seaborn.barplot()`, but in the current version (0.5.1) this feature seems not yet available. Looking at the returned `AxesSubplot` object, I could not find the way to set the line width to zero, or the color to fully transparent, although it has many methods, so I still hope there is a way to achieve this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.barplot(data = data, x = 'var1', color = '#007b7f')
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('fig.pdf')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will work too:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.barplot(data = data, x = 'var1', color = '#007b7f')
plt.setp(ax.patches, linewidth=0)
```

Answer (score 9):

After many attempts without success, I asked the question here, and soon I found the solution myself. So here it is: before plotting, the `patch.linewidth` parameter can be set with `seaborn.set_context()`:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_context(rc = {'patch.linewidth': 0.0})
ax = sns.barplot(...)
```